# Gem not building with new aggregated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have 2 projects that share the same models, so this models are packaged into a gem. I needed to add a new model to this gem so I created the migration and class needed, build the gem and then unpacked it onto the other projects and did

```
bundle install --local
```

The gem gets installed with it's new version but the new model file I added is not there. What am I missing?

Comment: Take a look in your `.gemspec` file. All included files need to be listed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Christoph's comment I was able to find the problem. My .gemspec file was using git-ls to list all the files that would be added to the gem, and I was testing without adding the new files to git. After I added them It was fine.